# Bash script works with one file, having trouble expanding the idea

Tags: bash

I stumbled upon the bastard operator from hell the other day and wanted to write up a script to generate excuses using the list from http://bofh.bjash.com/ExcuseBoard.html

I found a similar script from http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ballard/bofh/ which works from [this](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ballard/bofh/excuses) list with full excuses put together.

The script is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

line=$(($RANDOM%`grep -c '$' /home/USER/bofhserver/excuses`))
cat -n /home/USER/bofhserver/excuses|while read a b
do
    [ "$a" = "$line" ] && { echo "Your excuse is: $b"; break; }
done
```

I tried modifying this read from three separate files, with parts 1, 2, and 3 of each excuse coming together to create a random excuse. My attempt is as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash

line1=$(($RANDOM%`grep -c '$' /home/USER/bofhserver/pt1`))
line2=$(($RANDOM%`grep -c '$' /home/USER/bofhserver/pt2`))
line3=$(($RANDOM%`grep -c '$' /home/USER/bofhserver/pt3`))

cat -n /home/USER/bofhserver/pt1|while read a b
cat -n /home/USER/bofhserver/pt2|while read c d
cat -n /home/USER/bofhserver/pt3|while read e f
do
    [ "$a" = "$line1" ] && { echo "Your excuse is: $b"; }
    [ "$c" = "$line2" ] && { echo "$d"; }
    [ "$e" = "$line3" ] && { echo "$f" break; } 
done
```

I get a syntax error: unexpected end of file
What is a better way of doing this? My bastardization of that script is terrible, please forgive me.

Comment: BTW, consider using `shuf`. when you want a random line from a file (or a stream of them).

Comment: BTW, if you're going to `break` after only one iteration, why use a loop at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read from multiple files in a `while` loop, open each one on a different file descriptor, and put all your `read`s from those various descriptors in the condition end of the loop.

```
dir=~/bofhserver/
while read a b <&3 && read c d <&4 && read e f <&5; do
    echo "Your excuse is: $b $d $f"
done 3< <(shuf -n1 <"$dir"/pt1) 4< <(shuf -n1 <"$dir"/pt2) 5< <(shuf -n1 <"$dir"/pt3)
```

...that said, if you're generating a single excuse only, there's no reason for a loop at all; this could simply be:

```
echo "$(shuf -n1 <"$dir"/pt1) $(shuf -n1 <"$dir"/pt2) $(shuf -n1 <"$dir"/pt3)"
```

Using `shuf` gets us out of the randomization business altogether, substantially simplifying the code.

Comment: If you just want a single excuse every time, you don't need a `read` loop at all. Just call `shuf -n 1` on each file and that's it.

Comment: Yup; I do point that out to the OP in a comment on the question. With `-n 1` it won't iterate more than once anyhow.

Comment: Voila! Final script is simply two lines.

Comment: Thank you for the shuf usage! I knew there was a more eloquent way of presenting this.